# Compared with unmodified - Disabled in VS 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am using VS 2015 Enterprise and I have a project which has git as it's source control.

When you are viewing files in VS there is an option when you right-click on opened file content you see "Compared with unmodified". This option is disabled.

I don't change anything configuration wise in Git repo or in VS but this keep disabled/enabled few times. I don't know if there is way to keep this enabled all the time.

I can see through many other options like File-history, Annotation, etc.. only diff is disabled most of the time.

[image]